# How to invert last selection change (add/subtract)?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, selections

I edit product photos that quite often involve camouflage patterns and multiple colors. I use quick selection, then modify the edges where need be with lasso tools, to remove the background (well, to make a new layer with only the subject).

Problem is, often I hold CTRL when I intended to hold SHFT, and wind up adding to a selection instead of removing, or vice versa. Since these are often complex shapes, I hate to CTRL-Z and lose the alteration.

Is there a way to invert the last selection change? So that if I accidentally subtract a complex shape when I was trying to add it, I can hit one key combo which will take the last selection that was added and instead subtract, and vice versa?

Follow-up: What's the best way to do complex selections? Hitting Q is difficult as the color cast makes things harder to see, and curves seems like it's a lot more work than I'd like. I'm using Photoshop 10/CS3.

Comment: Check your preferences. Ctrl-z should step back 1 step (adding the selection) not remove anything more. You may have the prefs set to step back more than 1 step. [I can't test Photoshop 10/CS3]

Answer (score 1):

More a hint, than an answer: try to use brush instead of lasso to create your quick masks.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't think there is a way to choose a previous selection change, you could assign custom Keyboard Shortcuts to each selection method and toggle on will when you run into a problem.

Learn more about assigning keyboard shortcuts [here](http://on.aol.com/video/how-to-create-a-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-in-adobe-photoshop-cs3-86625054).

Answer (score 0):

I personally love shortcuts because it saves time, but "alt-control-Z" is step back.  You can also go to the "edit" and hit "step back".  Or make sure "history" is showing up.  You can step back to previous versions.